# Mosquitto vs Mosca horizontal scalability and resilience?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, mosca

I was planning on using Mosca or Mosquitto brokers (due they are open source) in order to achieve a scalable architecture with messages queue replication to avoid losing a message not yet delivered by the broker in an eventual failure of the broker.
As I read, mosquitto is a mature and very stable solution with the capacity of horizontal scalability using bridges. But I couldn't find any plugin to write messages into a database (common to all brokers), so I think that this is a limitation since if we have i.e. two brokers load balanced and one of them die, then all the messages of this broker cannot be delivered until the broker recover. 
Mosca in the other hand allows us to scale using Redis, and if the broker 1 die, then broker2 still can deliver messages because they are stored in a common database. And in that way I can use master-slave configuration of redis to avoid single point of failure.

**So my questions are:**

1) Is mosca a good choice for production?

2) Is it possible to use redis to allocate messages queues with mosquitto?

Answer (score 7):

Horizontal scalability is incredibly hard to add as an feature to MQTT brokers, since it requires engineering for that scalability from the start. Also, just replicating queues for undelivered messages won't help for resilience or fault-tolerance.

Even if it would be easy to add, I would NOT go with redis, since it essentially loses messages: https://aphyr.com/posts/283-jepsen-redis

If you want horizontal scalability, I'd recommend to check out a broker that has clustering, horizontal (or better: linear) scalability built-in and does allow network splits.

Here is a series about MQTT and clustering: http://www.hivemq.com/blog/clustering-mqtt-introduction-benefits/